# How to introduce soft page breaks in a HTML page?

Tags: html, css, xslt

I am writing a XSL script to parse various XMLs which follow the same structure. The goal is to parse the XMLs and convert them into HTML pages. For a lengthy XML, i would like to have a paginated HTML page (i.e. the parsed HTML text should appear in different `div`s where each `div` would represent a page). The content is supposed to move to the next `div` if the current `div` fills up or the current block-level element is too big to fit in the current page.

The trouble is since the output is dynamic I don't know when a page break would occur but I do know the dimensions of each page (`div`). Also an even bigger limitation is I need a non-Javascript solution for this problem for performance reasons.

I considered using CSS regions but the browser support for them is dismal, can anyone suggest me a solution or atleast point me in a right direction to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Except for CSS regions there is no **current** CSS only solution. Content inside a div cannot flow to another div.

Would a CSS3 Multiple Column Layout be of any help in your situation, that has better support (http://caniuse.com/#search=column)

Comment: i don't think it can be used for my purposes, can u suggest a way to proceed with it?